# XSLT Concatenation of fieldnames + parameter value for Dynamic Variable Name access

Tags: xslt

We have an XML file that we are trying to figure out a way to use dynamically.

the basics are this:

```
<part>
<...>
<fldMinPriceUSD>100.00</fldMinPriceUSD>
<fldMaxPriceUSD>110.00</fldMaxPriceUSD>
<fldMinPriceCAD>120.00</fldMinPriceCAD>
<fldMaxPriceCAD>130.00</fldMaxPriceCAD>
</part>
```

for each part that we've got, we want to use xslt on it to grab the part price based on the currency sent in through a parameter.  We don't want to use if-elses because we might want to grow the list of currencies (EUR, GBP, etc.) without changing our templates.

So, we'd want to use the `$dealerCurrency` parameter (that would be USD, CAD, etc.) to concat with fldMinPrice to grab that value.  Is this sort of thing even possible?  I've tried a number of things, but none seem to work.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(str[@name=concat('fldMinPrice', $dealerCurrency)], '#.00')"/>
```

and this doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. At the moment, by using **str** and **@name** you are looking for an element called **str** which has an attribute called **name** with a value of 'fldMinPriceUSD'. What you need is the **local-name()** function, along with **node()** to match any node.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(node()[local-name()=concat('fldMinPrice', $dealerCurrency)], '#.00')"/>
```

i.e. Match any node, with a name (excluding namespaces) of 'fldMinPrice' + your currency code.

Comment: yes, he's actually looking for e.g. `<str name="fldMinPriceUSD">` which is not definitely the wanted node to format. +1

Answer (score 0):

You guys are geniuses.  So, I was a little wrong in my original assessment.  Our actual XML looks like this (I had typed in the other part from memory... and I must have some corrupt memory somewhere... gotta get that replaced):

```
<double name="fldMaxPrice">20.0</double>
<double name="fldMaxPriceCAD">19.0</double>
<double name="fldMinPrice">18.0</double>
<double name="fldMinPriceCAD">17.1</double>
```

So, Tim C... your answer was perfect... for another part of the XML I was trying to do the same thing with.  empo, your example of what I was actually looking for helped me notice that my original post was ALMOST correct, except that I had a str where I should have had a double.  Changed str to double and voila!

So, I owe you guys a beer (unless you don't want to share, in which case, I'll get you each your own). :)  THANKS!